# How to retrieve data from cordova's inappbrowser to use in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, access-token, strongloop, inappbrowser

We’ve built out a Strongloop API that utilizes passport for third-party enterprise authentication; we are using `ionic 1.7.14` as our front-end.  Upon successful authentication, the user is redirected back to our Strongloop API server where an `accessToken` is created, and sent as a response to ionic front-end in both `json` format and as a cookie.   ​**How would the ionic retrieve this accessToken?**  We are using Cordova’s inappbrowser, and we are having trouble pulling data from inappbrowser to the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

s-thornton,

It sounds like Strongloop is sending a response, but the ionic app isn't finding it. If this is the case I would try this out. Using the inAppBrower to redirect the user to the sign-in page URL. Create an addEventListener that is listening for a specific path. Once found, you then create an $http.get to the last URL of your strongloop redirects. That will return a response from the server. Here is some sample code of what that would look like.

```js
win = window.open(url, '_blank','location=no');
win.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
  hasToken = event.url.indexOf('/me');
  if(hasToken > -1) {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://someserver.com/lastpage'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('LoginService Failed');
    });                    
  }
})
```